# Angular 4 automation using Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, data-driven, angular

I am trying to automate Angular 4 using Selenium, Just wanted to check if there are any good frameworks available? This info will give me a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) while developing some automated tests for one of my company's products which was written in AngularJS. It took me a little bit of time to get it set up/ configured properly, but once I'd done that, following the tutorials in detail, it worked very well.

Given this was my first experience of using automated testing, I would recommend it as easy to use & understand.